# PLS-00103 Encountered the symbol "BEGIN"

Tags: sql, database, plsql

This may be a repeat question but I'm very new with pl sql so I'm going to ask it anyways. I wrote a function that is supposed to determine if a varchar2 contains all alpha characters. It is defined as...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isAlpha (al IN VARCHAR2) RETURN CHAR;
BEGIN
FOR i in 1..LENGTH(al) LOOP
IF ASCII(SUBSTR(al, i, 1)) < 65 OR ASCII(SUBSTR(al, i, 1)) > 90
THEN RETURN 'F';
END IF;
END LOOP;
RETURN 'T';
END isAlpha;
```

I am receiving the error `Error(1,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN"` and I have no clue what it's getting at. I've tried debugging it for a decent amount of time with no luck. Thanks for any responses.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is slightly off - get rid of the `;` after the `RETURN` clause, and add an `AS`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isAlpha (al IN VARCHAR2) RETURN CHAR AS
BEGIN
...
```

See the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_function.htm#LNPLS01370) for further information

Comment: OMG thank you. I actually did this and forgot to refresh oracle sql developer earlier and had script output window minimized.. thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Hi in head "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isAlpha (al IN VARCHAR2) RETURN CHAR;" replaces ";" by IS.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized that I had tried with without it working but forgot to refresh sql developer.